# How to get netsuite’s current user details using suitescript?

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I need to get the current user’s credentials ( user id & password ) and compare it to the custom user id field and password field from a suitelet. Is there a way to do this?

Appreciate all your help!

Comment: Victor C, gave the correct answer.  Also, there is absolutely never a reason why you should try to capture user passwords.  Even if you have good intentions, gathering them creates a major security hole.

Comment: Thank you. The reason why im doing this is whenever a record has been change or edited, the user will need to enter his or her credentials before it gets save.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the current user's id (email) with nlapiGetContext().getUser() in 1.0 or runtime.getCurrentUser() in 2.0. However you cannot get the user's password for obvious security reasons.

Comment: Thank you. The reason why im doing this is whenever a record has been change or edited, the user will need to enter his or her credentials before it gets save.

Comment: Why does the user have to enter their credentials into the suitelet? They should already be authenticated through NetSuite unless you are using an external suitelet.

Comment: Correct, however, The user is requiring this for additional security steps when saving the record

Comment: The problem is that that is a reduction in security, not an additional security step.  Definitely a horrible idea to ever get access to user passwords.